# Using an attribute from another module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this file called **myService.js** where I define seasons by using heating or cooling systems. They are different especially in the case of a southern hemisphere country(e.g. Australia) where the seasons are reversed:

```
const myService= {};

const yearTimes = {
    JapanDefault: {
        heat: new YearTime('heat', 'Sep', 15, 'Mar', 1),
        cool: new YearTime('cool', 'Mar', 14, 'Sep', 14)
    },
    AustraliaDefault: {
        heat: new YearTime('heat', 'Jul', 1, 'Aug', 31),
        cool: new YearTime('cool', 'Sep', 1, 'Mar', 1) 
    }
};

myService.gettingAnalysis = function (site, Key) {
    return Promise.all([
        myService.findingHeat(site, Key),
        myService.findingCool(site, Key)
    ]).spread(function (heat, cool) {
        return { heating: heating, cooling: cooling };
    });
};
myService.findingHeat = function (site, Key) {
    return Promise.resolve(YearTime[Key] && YearTime[Key]['heat'] || defaults['heating']);
};

module.exports = myService;
```

In another file I must check for different cases, for example I should show a warning if there is use of heating in the summer. The code works fine for the northern hemisphere but wrong for the southern one because it detects that it is used heating system in summer(May, Jun) but in that particular case, that ones are winter months in the region.
This is the second file called **Breakdown.js**:

```
const _ = require('underscore');
const util = require('util');
const stats = require('simple-statistics');

const myService = require('./myService');
const SUM = 10;



...

check('must not indicate heating in summer', function (report) {
        const model = report.findSection('Breakdown').model;
        const heatingSeries = _.findWhere(model.series, { name: 'Space heating' });
        if (!heatingSeries || model.series.length === 1) {
            return;
        }

        const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);
        // TODO: "summer" varies per cohort
        const warnings = _.compact(_.map(['May', 'Jun'], function (monthLabel) {
            const summerIndex = _.indexOf(model.xAxisLabels, monthLabel);
            const heatingSummerCost = heatingSeries.data[summerIndex];
            if (heatingSummerCost > (totalAccounts * SUM)) {
                return {
                    month: monthLabel,
                    cost: heatingSummerCost,
                    accounts: totalAccounts
                };
            }
        }));
        this.should(!warnings.length, util.format('heating in summer recommended'));
    })
...
```

What I tried to do was to replace `['May', 'Jun']` with `myService.findingHeat(site, key)` or `myService.seasons.AustraliaDefault` in order to make it detect if it is not summer in that area and it is normal to have heating costs. 
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to replace an array `['July', 'Aug']` with an object of Season returned by `myService.findingHeatingSeason(report.site, report.cohort)` or `myService.seasons.AustraliaDefault` which may lead to some inconsistency. Can you please specify you Season constructor also?

Comment: As per the Season implementation ['July', 'Aug'] are the startMonth and endMonth of the season, isn't they? So you will have to create a method that returns [season.startMonth, season.endMonth]. Also `findingHeatingSeason` returns Promise.resolve so you will get response as `myService.findingHeatingSeason(report.site, report.cohort).then(function(data){console.log(data)})`.

Comment: yes, you're right. they are the startMonth and endMonth. in this case there are no other months between them but in the general case there could be. so I think that returning an array containig that months should be the solution